# Discord Bot Keeps Thinking After Responding Already

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I'm using py-cord and my Discord bot is thinking even after it has already sent a response.

```py
@client.slash_command()
async def response(ctx, input):
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    response = chatbot_client.response(input)
    await ctx.send(response.content)
```

I'm deferring since the .response function takes so long that the bot will exit out from the command if I don't.

Is there any fix to it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.slash_command()
async def response(ctx, input):
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    response = chatbot_client.response(input)
    await ctx.respond(response.content)
```

ctx.respond will respond to it: it will be viewable by anyone. Idk if i helped u. If no, you can dm me : Liam_#8834   .

Comment: fixed already after I searched documentation, your answer is valid though.

Comment: @walker You should be able to do await ctx.respond(input) Because rn, your making your code longuer for nothing. Unless there is another use of response.Just a suggestion :)

Comment: yea, I am using .respond now